# AS3 - String split webpage isn't working

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a long string of the HTML from a web page. I want to get to the content, and I found this just before the content:

```
<span style='margin-left:3px'><g:plusone size='medium' count='false'></g:plusone></span>
</div>
```

There is a line break through, and I don't think actionscript 3 likes linebreaks when using split. For example:

```
var theContent:Array = htmlSource.split("<span style='margin-left:3px'><g:plusone size='medium' count='false'></g:plusone></span></div>");
```

outputs one large array of the entire html source.

How do I make it so that I can successfully get the content? I tried /r, it does not work.

Comment: What happens if you don't insert the `</div>` part and your string ends with `</span>`?

Comment: It works, but there's ugly </div> at the start of the content. I tried doing another split for the </div>, but that doesn't seem to work, probably because of the invisible linebreak.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `\n`?

```
var theContent:Array = htmlSource.split("...snip...</span>\n</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a simple find + substr?

```
var sStr:String="<span style='margin-left:3px'><g:plusone size='medium' count='false'></g:plusone></span></div>";
var idx:int=htmlSource.indexOf(sStr);
var len:int=sStr.length;

var content:String=htmlSource.substr(idx+len);
```

Comment: I believe the problem is with the line break.

Comment: No it isn't a problem with the line break. Split handles a newline and/or carriage return character just like any other character. This means that it WILL and DOES work even if there are line breaks in the `htmlSource` string. However, one place where it can fail is if the string you are looking for (`<span ....`) has a line break in between. Because Flash does not ignore whitespace characters, so you'll have to get that exact string (along with any line breaks in it)

Comment: Nope, just tried it, does not work. Outputs the nearly the whole HTML expect with the first few characters of the doctype removed.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression?

```
var regExp:RegExp = /(<span style='margin-left:3px'><g:plusone size='medium' count='false'><\/g:plusone><\/span>\s?<\/div>)(.*)/s;
var content:String = htmlSource.replace(regExp, "$2");
```

The `"$2"` returns the second capturing group (ie., everything after the delimiter you provided).  If you want the array, use `match(regExp)` instead.

The `\s?` and the dotall flag (`s` at the end) get the job done.

Note: This is really lazy code, since you could easily cut down the regExp.  The principle thing is the effect.